# How can I "take control" of selecting TreeView items?

Tags: treeview, vscode-extensions

If you have a TreeView in a VS Code extension, when you click on the items in it, they get selected (highlighted green, in my color theme). Click away from them and they get un-highlighted. See the below screenshot, in the file explorer view:

[image]

I'd like to "take control" of this behavior. I want to disable the highlighting that happens by default when the user clicks on these items, disable the un-highlighting that happens when they click away, and control in my extension code when the items get highlighted. I'd like to do this in **my extension's** custom TreeView, not an existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'reveal' method of the treeview item. You can specify if it's to be 'selected' and also 'focused'.

Basically, you can change to the structure you want by forcing a refresh of the whole treeview. You probably already know that if you started making treeview extensions for vscode...

But then, right as it finishes re-rendering the tree, you 'reveal' a node, with the 'select' parameter option, to have that node as the selection in the tree. ...To have another node selected, just 'reveal' another one. (no need to force a full refresh of the treeview if it's only to have another node selected without changing the structure of the tree.)

see the 'reveal' method of the treeview here [treeview API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TreeView%3CT%3E)

Also see the [leointeg](https://github.com/boltex/leointeg) extension on vscode for actual code example of controlling which node is selected